# How to solve calls to web services that take too time?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a Windows RT application that needs to get data from a MVC WebApi server.
The problem is that the response can take from few seconds to 3 minutes.

Which is the best approach to solve it?

For now, I call async to the web api and put a long timeout value to avoid exceptions. Is it a good way? I do not like too much because the server have a open connection opened all time. Can it affect significantly to the server performance?

Is there some thing like "callback" but for web services? I mean that the server calls to the client to send the data.

Comment: Three minutes - wow, what does the server do? Anyway, if you're writing the server, one option could be to have a web service call to set off the calculation and then another one to poll for the result repeatedly now and again until it's ready. Though simply upping the timeout is probably a valid approach also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to get server to callback client, for example WCF duplex communication. However, such techniques will usually keep the connection open (in most cases this is TCP session). Most web servers do not support numerous concurrent requests and thus each prolonged call to the server will increment the number of concurrently connected clients. This will lead to heavy resource utilisation at the point where it shouldn't be. If you have many clients, such architecture is bound to fail.

REST requests shall be lightweight, small and fast. Consider using a database to store temporary results and worker servers, to process the load. This is a server-side problem, not client-side.

Comment: Good comment...  If the server-side activities cannot be performed more quickly, another way is to return a "token" for the requested operation and have the client poll for completion.  Not optimal, but may be better than keeping connections open.  You still have to manage server-side cleanup, though.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I solved it using WebSockets (thanks oleksii). It keeps the connection open but I avoid to poll for the result repeatedly. Now, when the server finishes the process, sends the data directly to the client. WebSockets is a protocol that relays over TCP and has been standardized.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket